# Importing CSV into web application

Tags: c#, excel, csv

I have a process that allows the user to download a spreadsheet, make some changes, and then upload those changes.

The upload method looks like -

```
    public DataTable ImportXLS(String SourceFilePath) {
        string ConnectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;" +
                        "Data Source=" + SourceFilePath + ";" +
                        "Extended Properties=Excel 8.0;";

        using (OleDbConnection cn = new OleDbConnection(ConnectionString)) {
            cn.Open();

            DataTable dbSchema = cn.GetOleDbSchemaTable(OleDbSchemaGuid.Tables, null);
            if (dbSchema == null || dbSchema.Rows.Count < 1) {
                throw new Exception("Error: Could not determine the name of the first worksheet.");
            }

            string WorkSheetName = dbSchema.Rows[0]["TABLE_NAME"].ToString();

            OleDbDataAdapter da = new OleDbDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM [" + WorkSheetName + "]", cn);
            DataTable dt = new DataTable(WorkSheetName);

            da.Fill(dt);

            return dt;
        }
    }
```

When I call the method locally, it works because I can see my local drives.

When deployed to the web server, and called like -

```
ExportImport _ei = new ExportImport();
DataTable dt = null;
dt = _ei.ImportXLS("C:\Users\mike\Desktop\mike.xls");
```

I get an error that "C:\Users\mike\Desktop\mike.xls" is not a valid path, obviously because it doesn't exist on the web server.

Has anyone had any experience with trying to upload files over the web and how do you resolve the file location issue?

Comment: You need to pass `_ei.ImportXLS()` the path to where the uploaded file is saved.

Comment: You can also first upload your file to the server, lets say to a `files` directory, and then open it with the URL towards that one. like `_ei.ImportXLS("/files/mike.xls");`

Comment: The users who use this functionality won't have access to the web server.  How would I upload it to the web server?

Comment: Figure it out! Thanks Henk Jansen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add a FileUpload control to your Asp.Net page. On a button click you need to the save the file on the server by calling:

```
FileUpload1.SaveAs("C:\\Uploads\\" + FileUpload1.FileName);
```

Afterwards you can call you method to process the file

```
ExportImport _ei = new ExportImport();
DataTable dt = null;
dt = _ei.ImportXLS("C:\\Uploads\\" + FileUpload1.FileName);
```

So the idea is to upload the file first to the server before processing it.

A link on using the FileUpload control (.Net 2.0)
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa479405.aspx

Answer (score 0):

You can use Server.MapPath to get the virtual location of your app. [Have a look at this article.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpserverutility.mappath%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)